# Why is python only available with cmd in administrator mode?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I just installed Python 3.3 and tried to run it through the command prompt:

> C:\Users\Foo>python

but I got this:

> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

which is weird, because I added it to PATH (`C:\Python33\`)

However, if I use an elevated command prompt then it runs fine:

> C:\Windows\system32>python
>
> Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AM
>   D64)] on win32
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

What is going on here? How can I run `python` in a normal, non-elevated command prompt?

EDIT: It seems there are two PATH in my system. The one in System Properties\Environment variables is this:

> C:\Python33\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\

and if I type `path` in a normal cmd I get this:

> PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32
>   \WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\
>   Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\b
>   in;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Window
>   s Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\

Why are there 2 `path` in my system, and why are they different? (one with python at the beginning, and one without)

Comment: in non-admin `cmd`, type `path`, what do you get? If `C:\Python33` is missing, add it, then you can use `python` in non-admin cmd.

Comment: it's indeed not in there, but it's in the PATH in System Properties/Environment Variables/System variables. Why is that and how can I add it to the path in cmd?

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx

Comment: that's exactly what I did

Answer (score 3):

Otherwise you can access it by the command "py"

Answer (score 2):

Try running `C:\Python33\python.exe` from your non-admin command prompt. This will rule out any permissions issues.

Don't forget to re-start the `cmd` shell after setting Environment Variables.

Comment: And after restarting the shell?

Comment: Yes. I reopened the shell multiple times, same result

Comment: What happens then if in that shell you enter `path=%PATH%;C:\Python33`? Can you post the output of `path`?

Comment: Oh after typing that I can now run it! Thanks a lot but can you explain what happened?

Comment: For some reason it's not in your path, or at least not in your path *correctly*. Setting the path like we did will only affect that shell, and won't help the next time. You say you have `C:\Python33` in your path in Environment Variables, but make sure the syntax is correct. There should be a semicolon separating it from the other elements. Something like `C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Python33`.

Comment: The syntax is correct, and I did close everything. I just restarted the machine and it is still working fine now, so I have no idea why.

Comment: @Chin Can this question be closed now?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the Path environment variable was only added for the administrator account.

try:

```
cmd >>> set path=C:\Python33;%path%
```

you can also check though typing in "environment variables" into the text search and check if the installation folder is present.

Answer (score -1):

It's the trailing slash in the first entry! Change
C:\Python33\
to
C:\Python33
and it should work. Had the same problem just now and found this post via google.